# ¿Como lograr enviar datos en conjunto con el archivo?

Tags: php, java

**Hola.**

Mi problema: logro enviar un archivo, pero necesito también enviar en conjunto a este unos datos que voy a recibir en mi **scirpt** **PHP** mediante `$_POST[]`, pero no los recibo. Envió la imagen y datos desde un programa **Java** y son recibidos por un **script** en mi servidor. Por ahora solo estoy enviando un solo dato en conjunto al archivo.

Este es mi método de carga completo:

```
public void upload(File file) throws Exception {
        URLConnection conn = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://mandaos2019.000webhostapp.com/CONECTOR.php");
            System.out.println("url:" + url);
            conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);



            String postData = "";

            InputStream imgIs = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] imgData = new byte[imgIs.available()];
            imgIs.read(imgData);

            String message1 = "";
            message1 += "-----------------------------4664151417711" + CrLf;
            message1 += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test_8.jpg\""
                    + CrLf;
            message1 += "Content-Type: image/jpeg" + CrLf;
            message1 += CrLf;


            // the image is sent between the messages in the multipart message.

            String message2 = "";
            message2 += CrLf + "-----------------------------4664151417711--"
                    + CrLf;

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711");
            // might not need to specify the content-length when sending chunked
            // data.
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf((message1
                    .length() + message2.length() + imgData.length)));

            System.out.println("open os");
            os = conn.getOutputStream();

            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            ps.print("&proyecto=" + "prueba");

            System.out.println(message1);
            os.write(message1.getBytes());
            // SEND THE IMAGE
            int index = 0;
            int size = 1024;
            do {
                System.out.println("write:" + index);
                if ((index + size) > imgData.length) {
                    size = imgData.length - index;
                }
                os.write(imgData, index, size);
                index += size;
            } while (index < imgData.length);
            System.out.println("written:" + index);

            System.out.println(message2);
            os.write(message2.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            System.out.println("open is");
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            char buff = 512;
            int len;
            byte[] data = new byte[buff];
            do {
                System.out.println("READ");
                len = is.read(data);

                if (len > 0) {
                    System.out.println(new String(data, 0, len));
                }
            } while (len > 0);
            System.out.println(conn);
            System.out.println("DONE");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Close connection");
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

    }
```

Esta fracción es la responsable de enviar los datos en conjunto:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());
ps.print("&proyecto=" + "prueba");
```

debería ser capaz de enviar este pequeño valor al **script** en mi servidor.

Mi código en mi **script PHP** lo que realiza es recibir el archivo y luego cargarlo a **Storage** de **Firebase**, pero requiere del valor de `$_POST["proyecto"]` para poder crear un directorio en el **Storage** por proyecto.

```
$target_path = "uploads/"; 

        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

        $name =  $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 

            $myfile = fopen($target_path, "r")  ;

            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 

            $this->bucket->upload($myfile, [
                'name' => $_POST["proyecto"] . "/" . $name
            ]);

        } else{ 
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
        }
```

**Gracias** y espero su apoyo.

Comment: revisa si 000webhost tiene las características que necesitas, a veces el problema está en el hosting. Por otro lado, agrega algún header con token de seguridad para evitar que cualquier usuario te llene de información no deseada

Comment: 000webhost si las tiene porque ya he trabajado con esto el problema radica al querer enviar estos datos en conjunto con el archivo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que intentas combinar dos tipos de codificaciones diferentes para el método POST (las cuales son la application/x-www-form-urlencoded y la multipart/form-data). Según la [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), para especificar datos que acompañen a la carga principal (en este caso, tu archivo), se necesita enviar igualmente en formato multipart, con la cabecera

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="proyecto"
```

Por lo que quedaría al momento de enviar la solicitud al servidor de la siguiente manera

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------4664151417711
Content-Length: 100000

-------------------------------4664151417711
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile"; filename="test_8.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<Codigo binario de tu archivo>
-------------------------------4664151417711
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="proyecto"

prueba
-------------------------------4664151417711--
```

El código final quedaría algo así

```
public void upload(File file) {
    String boundary = "-----------------------------4664151417711";
    URLConnection conexion;
    OutputStream os = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    int readedBytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.org");

        conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.setDoOutput(true);
        conexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        // Abrimos los streams necesarios
        // Es mejor utilizar streams con buffers
        os = conexion.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
        BufferedInputStream inputStreamImage = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        // Primero, enviamos las cabezeras necesarias
        writer.write("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test_8.jpg\"\r\n");
        writer.write("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        // Leemos el archivo y lo enviamos al stream de salida
        while((readedBytes = inputStreamImage.read(buffer)) != -1){
            if (readedBytes != buffer.length){
                // Si se leen menos datos que el buffer, lo recortamos
                stream.write(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, readedBytes));
            } else {
                // Si no, lo enviamos tal y como está
                stream.write(buffer);
            }
            // Enviamos los datos que actualmente tenga el buffer
            stream.flush();
        }
        writer.write("\r\n");

        // Enviamos los datos extras
        writer.write("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        writer.write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"proyecto\"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.write("prueba");
        // Cerramos la solicitud y liberamos los datos del buffer
        writer.write("--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        writer.flush();

        // Abrimos los streams para leer la respuesta del servidor
        // Igualmente, utilizamos streams con buffers, y un constructor de strings
        is = conexion.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((readedBytes = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
            response.append(new String(buffer, 0, readedBytes));
        }

        // Enviamos la respuesta a la consola
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null) os.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) { }
    }
}
```